# Reorder view's children. Nativescript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm looking for a way to rearrange `View`'s children.

```
<GridLayout id="parent">
  <AbsoluteLayout width="50" height="50" id="a"></AbsoluteLayout>
  <AbsoluteLayout width="50" height="50" id="b"></AbsoluteLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Suppose I want to rearrange `a` and `b` (so that they capture events in a different order). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to do the following:

```
container.removeChild(child)
container.insertChild(child, indexWhereToInsert)
```

This might mess up with user gestures (as it was in my case where I wanted to bring to the front the `AbsoluteView` that I was dragging), so you can reorder *all other* children.

In my case, I expanded it to a full component:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {ProxyViewContainer, View} from 'tns-core-modules/ui';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-reorderer', template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
})
export class ReorderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    private childViews: View[] = []
    private container: ProxyViewContainer

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.container = (<ProxyViewContainer>el.nativeElement);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.container.eachChildView(cv => {
            this.childViews.push(cv)
            return true
        })
    }

    // Call this from outside and pass the view you want to focus
    focus(view: View) {
        for (const v of this.childViews.reverse()) {
            if (v == view) continue

            this.container.removeChild(v)
            this.container.insertChild(v, 0)
        }

        this.childViews = []
        this.container.eachChildView(cv => {
            this.childViews.push(cv)
            return true
        })
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
<app-reorderer>
  <AbsoluteLayout width="50" height="50" id="a"></AbsoluteLayout>
  <AbsoluteLayout width="50" height="50" id="b"></AbsoluteLayout>
</app-reorderer>
```